# Save error to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php query to update a MySQL database, see below

```
$sql=("update hr_payroll set 
payroll_number='$payroll_number', 
tax_code='$tax',
bacs_ref='$bacs_ref',  
pay_frequency='$pay',
last_update_by='$user'
where employee_id='$employee'")or die('Could not connect: Error 23 ' . mysql_error());
```

If this query is successful a row is inserted into the DB, see below;

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO audit_hr_employees
(tab, employee, error_type, user, result)
VALUES ('4a', '$employee', 'info', '$user', 'success')";
}
```

This all works fine.... However if the query is not successful I want to do the same as above but add the error or the query into the database.

Below is a snippet of my code, I want the information to be added to the `error_info` column.

```
else
{       
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO audit_hr_employees 
(tab, employee, error_type, user, error_info)
VALUES ('4a', '$employee', 'warning', '$user', '  ')";
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question?

Comment: It's very likely that it is a duplicate.  When you execute your query, does the database return an error?  What is that error?  What even is the query that you're executing?  (Hint: This looks *wide open* to SQL injection, so you might be executing *anything*.)  Note also that you're not even checking what error was generated by the first query.  Why not?  Recording that there *is* an error is great and all, but recording *what that error was* seems like it would also be pretty useful.

Comment: Seems to be a different question.

Comment: your question is short on detail, as per the variables if they have values or not and if you're even querying that. If you want to save an error to a database, then you'll need to throw (catch) an exception and use that to write with.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I stand corrected.  Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, It's difficult to explain what I am trying to achieve. Which is a keyword?

Comment: @David Same here, never ceasing to learn also and makes it all that more exciting ;-)

Comment: @user3092953: It looks like what you're trying to achieve is to store a query which failed.  Which isn't itself a bad idea, if I'm being honest.  However, you need to also check *why* the query failed.  And if this query which is storing the failed query is *also* failing, well, that sounds like a potentially infinite rabbit hole...

Comment: @user3092953 Read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html you will see keywords and reserved words. You're also going to have to elaborate on your question as per a comment I left. I reopened the question so please give us more detail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Thank you :-)  I have updated the question, does it now make any sort of sense?

Comment: @user3092953: `"I want the information to be added to the error_info column."` - What information?  Before the edit it looked like you were trying to add the failed query itself.  Has that changed?  It also looks like you're trying to mix two different ways of interacting with your database (using `mysql_error()` and using `$conn->query()` looks suspect), which won't work at all.  (Also note: Defining a string variable in PHP will never result in a SQL error.)  The main issue still seems to be that your query is failing but you're not getting the error message from MySQL.

Comment: @David - Ideally I would like to add the failed query to the database

Comment: @user3092953: A "query within a query" definitely has the potential for lots of syntax problems if you just directly add it to the string like that.  All the more reason to be using prepared statements with query parameters so the database knows to treat the whole "inner query" as just a string to be saved.  So you're *definitely* going to want to use prepared statements here and stop directly putting those variables in that string.  (As a bonus, it's protection against SQL injection as well.)  But, again, you're also going to want to look at the error.  Not sure why you still won't do that...

Comment: You are still **as per your other very similiar question** No issueing the query to the database. Do we assume you just left this out for brevity?

Comment: @David Thats just what I said on his other very similiar question, re: the rabbit hole.

Comment: If you are not absolutely sure that the database failure is not due to the database crashing, all of a sudden its not there any more, you cannot sensibly attempt to write to it again.

Comment: Anyway : what is the possible use of adding a message saying `this query had an error` which it a bit like recording `Woops` without also grabbing the  `mysqli_error($con)` and storing that as well

Comment: Why do you think that MYSQL creates a `error log` on a flat file on disk. I suggest its because there are situations that even the developers of MYSQL could not possibly code around in order to ensure they recorded ALL errors where someone would be able to see them regardless of what happens to MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're connecting to MySQL via PHP's PDO interface. You can use the `errorInfo()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to retrieve the most recent error message and use that in place of your blank string:

```PHP
$err = $dbh->errorInfo();

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO audit_hr_employees 
(tab, employee, error_type, user, error_info)
VALUES ('4a', '$employee', 'warning', '$user', $err[2])";
```